# Laravel Notifications System: method notify does not exist.

Tags: laravel, notifications

I created a notification system and I am trying to to use the *notify* method to send a message.  Instead, I am getting

> Method notify does not exist.

I included at the top of my Controller `use Notifications\EmailClientOfAccount;`.  Here is my code.  I can include more if that will be helpful.

```
foreach ($emails as $email){
                $client = User::where('email', $email)->get();
                $notificationOptions = EmailClientOfAccount::sendEmailToClient($email, $user);
                $client->notify(new EmailClientOfAccount($notificationOptions));
            }
```

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi, already did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your `User` model you imported `Notifiable` trait

After class, you should have something like this:

```
class User ... {

   use \Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
```

to make Laravel trait imported. This trait use 2 other traits and in `\Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications` there is `notify` method that you want to use.